# O que é encadeamento de métodos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Em linguagens orientadas à objectos, existe um conceito conhecido como `method chaining` ou `encadeamento de métodos` para o português.

> O que é isto exatamente ?
>
> Como seria a implementação dessa técnica num aplicativo PHP ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Encadeamento de métodos** é uma técnica que possibilita executar diversos métodos em um objeto dentro de uma mesma instrução ([geralmente separada por ponto-e-vírgula](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)).

Tais métodos, em geral, possuem algum efeito colateral e não retornam valores significativos.

## Como funciona

Normalmente você executa diversos métodos de um objeto da seguinte forma:

```
class Classe {
    public function executar_isto() {
        //faz algo importante
    }
    public function executar_aquilo() {
        //faz algo mais importante
    }
}
$objeto = new Classe();
$objeto->executar_isto();
$objeto->executar_aquilo();
```

Repare que esses métodos não retornam valor.

Entretanto, se a chamada de vários métodos é comum nesse objeto, você pode reescrevê-los de forma que eles retornem `$this` e as chamadas poderão ser encadeadas:

```
class Classe {
    public function executar_isto() {
        //faz algo importante
        return $this;
    }
    public function executar_aquilo() {
        //faz algo mais importante
        return $this;
    }
}
$objeto = new Classe();
$objeto->executar_isto()->executar_aquilo();
```

Pode parecer confuso a princípio, mas depois que se entende que as chamadas são feitas sempre no mesmo objeto, que é retornado por cada método, você percebe que isso é na verdade mais fácil de ler e "limpo" do que repetir o objeto várias vezes.

Note que agora os vários métodos são executados dentro de uma única instrução, isto é, sem necessidade de quebrar as chamadas em várias chamadas separadas por ponto-e-vírgula. Isso permite realizar operações *inline*, por exemplo, em parâmetros de métodos e torna o código menos *verboso*:

```
$outro_objeto->algum_metodo_legal(
        $objeto->executar_isto()->executar_aquilo(),
        //outros parâmetros
    );
```

## Interfaces fluentes e *builder pattern*

O encadeamento de métodos sozinho não é algo muito atrativo. Porém, se usado com outros padrões como *fluent interfaces* e *builder pattern*, o resultado começa a ficar bem interessante.

Se quiser uma leitura adicional, tenho um artigo chamado [*Construindo objetos de forma inteligente: Builder Pattern e Fluent Interfaces*](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/) sobre o assunto, mas com alguns exemplos em Java.

### Interfaces fluentes

Basicamente, interfaces fluentes consistem em métodos encadeados cujos nomes são significativos para uma determinada operação. Por exemplo:

```
$aviao->abastecer()->decolar()->voarPara("Disney")->pousar();
```

Algumas APIs vão mais longe e criam quase uma [DSL (*Domain Specific Languages*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), como é, por exemplo, o caso da biblioteca [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), com a qual é possível fazer:

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM TABELA')->fetchAll();
```

### *Builder pattern*

Outra aplicação do encadeamento de métodos é na construção de objetos. Fiz um [pequeno exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/WLaiko) para ilustrar.

Suponha que sua loja virtual tenha uma cesta de compras com itens, representada pela classe a seguir:

```
class Cesta {
    private $itens;
    public function __construct(array $itens) {
        $this->itens = $itens;
    }
    public function show() {
        echo "Minha cesta:\n";
        foreach ($this->itens as $item) {
            echo $item."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Note que a implementação de `Cesta` é imutável, isto é, uma vez construído o objeto, ele não pode mais ser alterado. Há várias vantagens nisso, mas não vou entrar em detalhes aqui. A ideia é que você precisa passar todos os itens de uma vez.

Para facilitar a construção da `Cesta`, vamos implementar uma calsse *builder*:

```
class CestaBuilder {
    private $itens = array();
    static public function create() {
        return new static;
    }
    public function adicionar($item) {
        $this->itens[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }
    public function build() {
        return new Cesta($this->itens);
    }
}
```

O nosso *builder* permite a composição dos itens em sua própria instância e em algum ponto o método `build` é chamado para retornar uma instância de `Cesta` com os itens coletados.

Exemplo de uso:

```
$minha_cesta = CestaBuilder::create()
    ->adicionar("Pão")
    ->adicionar("Queijo")
    ->adicionar("Mortadela")
    ->build();
```

## Considerações

Mais uma vez, tudo isso pode parecer um pouco confuso a princípio, mas uma vez que se entende bem tais conceitos, dificilmente você vai querer usar outra coisa.

O uso de métodos encadeados, interfaces fluentes e *builders* deixa seu código mais limpo e intuitivo.

No caso de uma API, evita você ter que ficar olhando a todo momento na documentação procurando quais métodos deve chamar, já que muitas vezes o auto-completar das IDEs já mostra as possibilidades de uso da classe. Isso fica mais evidente uma vez que se acostume ao uso dos padrões, pois ao usar novas APIs você meio que já sabe o que esperar delas.

## O que não é encadeamento de métodos

Há uma forma "falsa" de encadear métodos, que na verdade é uma má prática. Consiste em chamar vários métodos em sequência, aparentemente da mesma forma, mas na verdade acessando vários objetos diferentes.

Por exemplo:

```
$contato = $empresa->getProjeto("foo")->getFuncionario("bar")->getNome();
```

Embora o código acima seja intuitivo e compacto, ele traz riscos que um bom *design* não deveria trazer.

Cada método retorna um objeto diferente, logo pode ser que em alguma chamada o objeto não seja encontrado e `null` seja retornado. Um erro irá ocorrer sem possibilidade de tratamento.

Além disso, em geral deve-se evitar que um código qualquer tenha conhecimentos sobre vários níveis de objetos, pois isso aumenta muito o acoplamento.

A alternativa nesse caso é criar um método em `Empresa` para retornar a informação desejada. Exemplo:

```
$contato = $empresa->getNomeContatoPorProjeto("foo","bar");
```

Comment: Ótima resposta @utluiz, porém ficou uma pequena dúvida na minha cabeça quanto a isso? Me disseram que os métodos encadeados recriam a instância do objeto, isso é uma verdade? **Obs:** não criei uma pergunta nova para isso, para que não receba como duplicata.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Depende. No meu exemplo o Builder retorna a própria instância, então não tem criação de instância. Isso porque o Builder é uma classe transitória e pode ter seu estado alterado. Entretanto se você trabalha com objetos imutáveis, então cada chamada a algum método pode criar outra instância, que retorna um novo objeto imutável com novo valor. Não sei de nenhum exemplo em PHP assim de cara, mas um exemplo clássico é o BigDecimal do Java.

Comment: Oi @utluiz, muito obrigado pelo retorno e por esclarecer minha dúvida!

Comment: no create() você colocou "return new static", eu poderia instanciar o objeto dentro da funcao e retornar o objeto? Tipo "$obj = new CestaBuilder(); return $obj". É uma má pratica?

Comment: @ivanveloso Sim, `new CestaBuilder` funcionaria. Para falar a verdade, faz tanto tempo que eu não lembro porque usei o `new static` - que usa *late binding* e é importante no caso de herança - neste exemplo. Provavelmente era algo com o que eu estava trabalhando e acabou ficando.