# Chamar um método que chama outro método da mesma classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Exemplo tenho a classe **`Metodo`**:

```
public class Metodo {

    private String string;

    public String mostrar(String nome, String sobrenome){
        this.string = "Nome: " + nome + "Sobrenome: " + sobrenome;

        return string;
    }

    public void show(){
        System.out.println(this.string);
    }
}
```

E a classe que testa esse método:

```
package testarMetodo;

    public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Metodo metodo = new Metodo();
        metodo.mostrar("Aline", "Gonzaga").show();          
    }
}
```

Só que não funciona. Eu só queria pegar o retorno do outro método e mandar exibir com o método **`show()`**.

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deve usar um [*padrão de projeto*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software) chamado [Interface Fluent](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/), que encadeia os métodos de forma facilitar no desenvolvimento, tem um texto bacana explicativo sobre [`Interface Fluent` e `Builder Patterns`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105433/54880) no ***SOPt*** que define cada um em um momento do desenvolvimento, mas vamos focar no seu código.

Alterações na ***classe*** `Metodo`:

```
public class Metodo
{

    private String string;
    public Metodo mostrar(String nome, String sobrenome)
    {
         this.string = "Nome: " + nome + " Sobrenome: " + sobrenome;
         return this;
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(this.string);
    }
}
```

sendo que o método deve ser do mesmo tipo da classe e no seu retorno faz referencia a si próprio (`this`). Resumo do código que deve ser no método:

```
public Metodo mostrar(String nome, String sobrenome)
{
    //code ...
    return this;
}
```

Ai vai funcionar como espera:

```
package testarMetodo;

public class Teste 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Metodo metodo = new Metodo();
        metodo
            .mostrar("Aline", "Gonzaga")
            .show(); 
    }
}
```

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/jEP10S)

**Referencias:**

- [Padrão de Projetos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software)
- [Construindo objetos de forma inteligente: Builder Pattern e Fluent Interfaces](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/)
- [Design Patterns para melhorar seus testes, Parte 1: Builder e Fluent Interfaces](http://stefanteixeira.com.br/2015/07/29/design-patterns-para-melhorar-seus-testes-parte-1-builder-fluent-interfaces/)
- [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105259/o-que-%C3%A9-encadeamento-de-m%C3%A9todos)
- [Another builder pattern for Java](http://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java)
- [Builder](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder)

Comment: Uau funcionou!...

Comment: @gonz, legal, dê uma lida no link tem um ligeira diferenças principalmente pra `Java`, mas, fico feliz e ter ajudado.

Comment: Com certeza amigo. Irei ler sim. =) Qunado chegar em casa...