# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string. laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.2

Estou tendo problemas com uma pesquisa relativa no `Laravel`. Dou opção de várias pesquisa na tela, são elas:

- data inicial
- data final
- status,
- e de quem é

porém a pessoa pode pesquisa de forma unitária, por exemplo: quero pegar todos com `status` **Ativo**, ou todos de uma determinada **pessoa**, e por ai vai.

Dois desta pesquisa são obrigatórios, ou seja, em todos os casos terão a **data inicial** e **final**.

No `Controller` que eu estou recebendo este dados estou fazendo assim:

```
$inicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('dataInic'))->format('Y-m-d');
$final = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('dataFim'))->format('Y-m-d');
$flgStatus =  $request->get('FlgStEncomenda');
$pessoa = $request->get('CdPessoa');
$clientes = Pessoa::lists('NmPessoa', 'id')->all();

$pedidos = Encomenda::where('created_at', '<=', $inicial)
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', $final)
                   .(($flgStatus == 'null')? '' : "->('FlgStEncomenda', ".$flgStatus.")")
                   .(($pessoa == '')? '->get()' : "->('CdPessoa', ".$pessoa.")");
```

Ao fazer isto a tela me retorna o seguinte **erro**:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer estas pesquisas, levando em consideração que o dado poderá vir ou não e isto precisa ser tratado ao fazer a pesquisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é de conversão: um objeto [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) não pode ser convertido para `string`, na verdade, a sua concatenação que é inválida.

***Como resolver:***

*Por partes, trabalhando com a facilidade do [encadeamento de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165246/54880) que o* [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) *tem implementado*.

<sub>***Observação***: utilize [`$request->input`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input) se não tiver retorno o seu valor padrão é [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.null.php) e no [`if`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php) utilize [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) para conferir se tem informação ou é nula.</sub>

*No seu código ficaria basicamente assim:*

```
$inicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('dataInic'))->format('Y-m-d');
$final = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('dataFim'))->format('Y-m-d');
$flgStatus =  $request->input('FlgStEncomenda');
$pessoa = $request->input('CdPessoa');
$clientes = Pessoa::lists('NmPessoa', 'id')->all();

$pedidos = Encomenda::where('created_at', '<=', $inicial)
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', $final);


if (!is_null($flgStatus))
{
    $pedidos = $pedidos->where('FlgStEncomenda',$flgStatus);
}    

if (!is_null($pessoa))
{
    $pedidos = $pedidos->where('CdPessoa',$pessoa);
}

$resultado = $pedidos->get();
```

Observe que no código a variável `$pedido` recebeu várias vezes `$pedidos->where` (pode ser qualquer comando do [`builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html)) se no [`if`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php) ***fosse satisfeito***, isso garante que eu sempre retorno a última alteração do [`builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) e no final é chamado um `get()` com os filtros que foram escolhidos.

***Referencias:***

- [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html)
- [Retrieving Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input)
- [null](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.null.php)
- [if](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php)
- [is_null](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php)

Comment: me tire uma duvida, o meu data no banco tem dia, mes, ano, hora, segundo, minuto e na minha pesquisa so tem dia mes e ano, tem importância isto ?

Comment: Todos os casos da pesquisa esta voltando vazio, mesmo se tem algum resultado

Comment: acho que esta com problema na hora

Comment: encontrei o erro, eu estava confundindo os itens da data, o certo é >= depois <=. Funcionou perfeitamente agora.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues agora que vi seus comentários. kkk