# JSON em Laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, json, laravel, query

Queria saber como faço pra mandar os dados da query em json através do controller e como a view deveria receber eles.

Controller:

```
$dados = $req->all();

$query = "";

if($dados['filter'] == 1)
{

  $query = User::where('id','LIKE','%'.$dados['search'].'%');
}
else if($dados['filter'] == 2)
{

  $query = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$dados['search'].'%');
}
else if($dados['filter'] == 3)
{

  $query = User::where('email','LIKE','%'.$dados['search'].'%');
}

return view('users.index')->with([$users->$query]);
```

View:

```
  @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Comment: Como você colocou o return da sua função no controller? Você só precisa colocar o view/('view')->with([$var_para_chamar_no_blade -> $query]);

Comment: entendi, vou estar tentanto

Comment: Luiz, olhe como estava o return eu editei na publicação

Comment: Luiz, eu coloquei, porém esta dando erro de Object

Comment: Não é necessário usar saudacoes aqui, se quiser saber mais o porquê, leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/28595

Comment: Obrigado! Sou novo aqui

Comment: faltou a atribuição da variável p chamar no blade, tenta assim:
return view('users.index')->with(['users' -> $query]);

Comment: ele da esse erro: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: boa.. acho q faltou ai o ->get() no final. atualiza o retorno para: ->with(['users' -> $query->get()]);

Comment: é isso mesmo: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Cara, mesmo erro

Comment: cara tem algum bo na query ai, troca o LIKE por like, se não rolar tenta ver aqui q é o mesmo BO.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165859/object-of-class-illuminate-database-eloquent-builder-could-not-be-converted-to-s

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
$dados = $req->all();

$query = "";

if($dados['filter'] == 1)
{

  $users = User::where('id','LIKE','"%'.$dados['search'].'%"')->get();
}
else if($dados['filter'] == 2)
{

  $users = User::where('name','LIKE','"%'.$dados['search'].'%"')->get();
}
else if($dados['filter'] == 3)
{

  $users= User::where('email','LIKE','"%'.$dados['search'].'%"')->get();
}

return view('users.index', compact('users'));
```

Sua `view` pode deixar da mesma maneira.

Aconselho você tirar isso da `Controller` e separar em uma outra camada, uma `Service` por exemplo.