# Chamando vários métodos na mesma instância de uma classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso:

```
Class::methodA()->methodB()->methodC()...;
```

Tenho uma classe View (MVC) na qual passo parâmetros para criação de variáveis (assign). Atualmente está assim:

```
View::assign('var1', 'Variável 1');
View::assign('var2', 'Variável 2');
View::render('layout');
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
View::render('layout')->assign('var1', 'Variável 1')->assign('var2', 'Variável 2')
```

Comment: [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método assign tem de retornar a própria classe:

se o método for public:

public static function assign(){
  return $this;
}

Se o método for public static:

public static function assign(){
  $class = new Class();
  return $class;
}