# Multiplos wheres automáticos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter

Estava vendo no `CodeIgniter` que existe uma forma de inserir vários 'where' na classe `DB`:

Exemplo:

```
$this->db->where('id', 1)
     ->where('name', 'Jão')
     ->where('lastname', 'Fulaninho')
     ->get('users')
     ->result();
```

A questão aqui é que é no `where` é inseridos automaticamente algumas palavras a cada novo `where` que eu coloquei à cima `where (...) or where (...)` e assim em diante.

Como se chama essa forma de programar na `POO`. Para que eu faça as minhas próprias classes dessa maneira.

Comment: Acho que é isso: [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/91)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105259/o-que-%c3%a9-encadeamento-de-m%c3%a9todos)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não, pois lá ele perguntou o que era encadeamento de métodos, aqui estou perguntando 'como se chama' essa forma de programar que coloquei a cima.

Answer (score 1):

Alguns falaram de encadeamentos de métodos, e está correto. Mas acho também importante citar que também pode ser chamado de [*Fluent Interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106955/o-que-%C3%A9-fluent-interface).

Mas falando mais especificamente do Active Records do Codeigniter, creio que o termo mais fácil para você achar referências que te ajudem a criar uma funcionalidade similar seria: *Sql Query Builder* (Construtor de Query Sql).

Veja algumas bibliotecas de exemplos:

- [Pixie Query Builder](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie)
- [Doctrine Query  Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)