# Passando valores entre funções no PHP

Tags: php

No Laravel é comum trabalharmos com funções como `url()->to(string)` ou `redirect()->route(string)` onde essa "segunda função" `->to(string)` estende ou retorna um valor para a primeira função `url()`.

Como isso é feito na prática em PHP?

Tentei fazer algo parecido mas não deu certo:

```
function to($path)
{
    return $path;
}

/**
 * Return the base theme url.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function url(string $path = null)
{   
    if(isset($path))
        $path = "/{$path}";

    return get_template_directory_uri() . $path;
}
```

Execução:

```
url()->to('teste')
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105259/o-que-%c3%a9-encadeamento-de-m%c3%a9todos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que a função de auxílio `url()` do Laravel retorna um objeto do tipo [`Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html). Essa classe, por si só, possui o método [`to`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_to), que retorna uma *string*.

Fazer `url()->to("/")`, por exemplo, seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
$url = url();
return $url->to("/");
```

Onde `$url` é um objeto do tipo `UrlGenerator`, citado acima.