# Método chamando método

Tags: php, método

Pelo meu conhecimento só consigo chamar o método de uma classe só se eu instanciar ou se o método for estático!

Eu mesmo só consigo fazer algo tipo `class->metodo('var')` ou `class::metodo('var')`.

Porém já vi em alguns códigos algo tipo `class->metodo('var')->outrometodo('')`.

O próprio Drupal usa algo parecido. Ex:

```
db_select('node', 'n')->execute()->fetchCol();
```

Como que se faz esse tipo de chamada, e quais serias as vantagens?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic mesmo sendo em java a ideia é a mesma?

Comment: Sim. É a mesma lógica.

Comment: Sim, veja funcionando [repl.it](https://repl.it/ODrF/1)

Comment: Realmente! Li aqui a pergunta e a resposta, e funcionou! Recomenda que eu exclua a pergunta?

Comment: Não pode deixar... Fica como duplicata da outro.

Comment: Mas uma questão não foi respondida! Como está na pergunta! Quais seriam as vantagens? Representa algum ganho significativo? Há alguma recomendação para quando usar ou não?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105259/o-que-%c3%a9-encadeamento-de-m%c3%a9todos/105433#105433 leia