# Utilizar mais de um -> na mesma linha de codigo PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eu fiz a minha transição do Java para o PHP e recentemente esbarrei em algo que eu costumava fazer em Java mas não estou conseguindo fazer em php.

O seguinte código cria um objeto do tipo "User"

```
public function validateUser() {
    //Check if information entered by user is valid
    $user = new User($_POST);
    new UserControl($user);
}
```

Preciso fazer uma validação se o cpf é numerico, antes de prosseguir com a validação com a fórmula.
Em Java eu iria utilizar algo como:

```
int cpf = this.getUser().getUserCpf();
```

O código em php está assim:

```
class UserControl {
private $user;

public function __construct($user) {
   $this->setUser($user);
}


public function validateIntegers() {
  $cpf = $this->getUser()->getUserCpf();
  is_numeric($cpf);
}
```

Porém a mesma lógica não se aplica. Existe alguma outra forma de usar essa orientação a objetos no PHP? Ou não é possível fazer algo dessa forma?

Comment: [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/91)

Comment: Não deu para entender exatamente onde é o problema. `$cpf` vem nulo?

Comment: Exatamente. o $cpf fica normal depois de criar o objeto User, mas quando passo $user como parametro pra construção da classe UserControl ele fica nulo.

Comment: Posta o código de `getUser()`

Comment: public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

Comment: Tenho que castar isso como return (object) $this->user;?

Comment: Não precisa de cast. Precisa debugar ou dar uns `var_dump()` para encontrar o local do problema, olhando esse código parece correto.

Comment: Achei o erro...
estava assim: 
`new DbrControl();


require_once "../model/User.php";


require_once "./UserControl.php";`


eu fiz isso:
`require_once "../model/User.php";


require_once "./UserControl.php";


new DbrControl();`

e funcionou